# Does String.to_atom("some-known-string") create a new atom in the atom-table each time?

Tags: erlang, elixir

Does `String.to_atom("some-known-string")` create a **new atom** in the atom-table each time?

If ***NO***, then *what* is the point of `String.to_existing_atom/1`?

If ***YES***, then *why*? since `String.to_atom("some-known-string")` will always give the same result ... and the atom-table is **never** garbage collected

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you are always using the same string, it may only create a new atom the first time it is run. After that, assuming continued use of the same string, it will not create new atoms.

The reason there is also `to_existing_atom` is to help prevent filling the atom table with unknown information.

```
iex(1)> String.to_existing_atom("foo")
** (ArgumentError) argument error
    :erlang.binary_to_existing_atom("foo", :utf8)
iex(1)> String.to_atom("foo")
:foo
iex(2)> String.to_existing_atom("foo")
:foo
```

As you can see, when I first try to call `to_existing_atom`, the process actually crashes because that atom is not in the atom table. However, if I use `to_atom` to ensure it exists, I can now call `to_existing_atom` and I do not get a crash.

Comment: I understand your reasoning, but most documentation seem to imply calling string.to_atom would quickly fill up your atom table ... as you have explained, it wont, necessarily. One is given the impression that String.to_atom creates atoms over and over, hence the danger to your VM

Comment: You should not be calling `to_atom` on user input. This can quickly fill your atom table. Even if you only expect the user to enter a small handful of values. This is because they still can enter random garbage which could fill your atom table and kill your application.

Comment: it leaves us with the requirement: pre_load know atoms

Comment: Or use strings as your datatype.

Comment: Except where and when to you call String.to_atom? That is **strongly discouraged** https://stackoverflow.com/a/54625085/719689

Answer (score 1):

An example use-case:

For process isolation, I need to dynamically generate a series of ets tables by partition number. I will have a fixed number of partitions -- but I can't name ets tables using anything but an atom, so {:my_table, num} is not an option.

Therefore, each process with a partition creates an atom based on a {name, number} combo.

`String.to_atom("my_table" <> Integer.to_string(i))`

Creating atoms from a source outside your direct control *is* dangerous, though, since it could crash your BEAM. Thus, to_existing_atom is a nice way to sanitize incoming data.

Answer (score 0):

In elixir atoms are **immutable**.

```
field(q, ^(String.to_existing_atom k))
```

In this example we are using existing_atom because we are fetching data form DB and `existing` make sure the field is valid. It is useful and in such scenarios.

Comment: this means that you have called to_atom at some point first, before calling to_existing_atom

Comment: You don't actually have to call `to_atom` directly. If you have `:foo` in your code, that atom will exist in your system and calling `String.to_existing_atom("foo")` will work.

Comment: yes exactly. If its already present you can call it by `existing_atom`

Comment: @hammadahmed so, if i read you correctly, just using Structs as our internal data-types guarantees our known-atoms are pre-loaded. Nice.