# Convert a map into a keyword list in Elixir

Tags: elixir

I have a map of the form:

```
%{"browser_name" => "Chrome", "platform" => "linux"}
```

and I need to convert it to a keyword list:

```
[browser_name: "Chrome", platform: "linux"]
```

What's the best way of achieving this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Wouldn't this work:

```
 def convert_to_klist(map) do
   Enum.map(map, fn({key, value}) -> {String.to_existing_atom(key), value} end)
 end
```

Comment: Beware of `String.to_atom/1` is vulnerable to atom DoS attack.

Comment: try this instead: `String.to_existing_atom/1`

Comment: And please do not use CamelCase in function names

Answer (score 11):

I would put it here for the sake of future readers.

While one surely might blindly call [`String.to_atom/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/String.html#to_atom/1) here and there, that approach is **strongly discouraged** due to its vulnerability to atom DoS attacks.

Here is the excerpt from Erlang docs:

> Atoms are not garbage-collected. Once an atom is created, it is never removed. The emulator terminates if the limit for the number of atoms (1,048,576 by default) is reached.
>
> Therefore, converting arbitrary input strings to atoms can be dangerous in a system that runs continuously. If only certain well-defined atoms are allowed as input, [`list_to_existing_atom/1`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#list_to_existing_atom-1) can be used to guard against a denial-of-service attack. (All atoms that are allowed must have been created earlier, for example, by simply using all of them in a module and loading that module.)
>
> — http://erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/commoncaveats.html#list_to_atom-1

That said, whether you receive the map from the external untrusted source (e. g. it’s the parameters in the call to your API or something,) you **must not** use `String.to_atom/1` and should use [`String.to_existing_atom/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/String.html#to_existing_atom/1) instead.

Otherwise, the intruder with a simple random generator for keys would blow up your *ErlangVM* without any issue.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the `Keyword.new` function and pass in a transform function as the second argument.

```
Keyword.new(%{"browser_name" => "Chrome", "platform" => "linux"}, fn {k,v} -> {String.to_existing_atom(k), v} end)
> [browser_name: "Chrome", platform: "linux"]
```

Although this is basically equivalent to the accepted answer from @NiteRain, I think it's a bit more explicit and shows future readers of your code your intentions.

See: https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Keyword.html#new/2

Answer (score 7):

For future reference. You can also use [Enum.into/3](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#into/3)

```
%{"browser_name" => "Chrome", "platform" => "linux"}
|> Enum.into([], fn {k, v} -> {String.to_existing_atom(k), v} end)
```

or in its shorter version:

```
%{"browser_name" => "Chrome", "platform" => "linux"}
|> Enum.into([], &{String.to_existing_atom(elem(&1,0)), elem(&1,1)})
```